# Substituting all numbers in a string with a different character in python

Tags: python

I want to take all number characters `[0,9]` within a string and replace them with the character 8. I'm sure there's a simple method but I just can't seem to find it! All related questions on here are for deleting the numbers, not for substituting with a different character.

e.g. "`word 8008 7  str50ing2 " ---> "word 8888 8 str88ing8` "

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try pasting your question's title into Google? The first result that turns up (after this question, of course) is the [documentation for regular expressions in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: I'm sure that would have helped but I'm new to python, I was not aware of "regular expressions" before. But yes I did google a lot but could not find satisfactory answer.

Comment: Exactly - using Google to find relevant documentation, and then reading that documentation (or, if it's too advanced, Googling tutorials about those topics), is how you become aware of these things.

Comment: Google is a big place, but thanks for you advice.

Comment: It was the _very first result_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression module and more specifically the [substitute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) (`sub`) method.
    import re
    string = "word 8008 7 str50ing2 " # ---> "word 8888 8 str88ing8 "

```
print  re.sub(r'\d', '8', string)
```

Does the trick, the output is:

```
word 8888 8 str88ing8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using just native functions:

```
a = "word 8008 7  str50ing2 "    
for x in range(0,9): a = a.replace(str(x),'8')
```

should work; outputs:

```
>>> a
'word 8888 8  str88ing8 '
```